# systemd: How to clear an entry when overriding a unit file

Tags: systemd

A service on my machine has a default unit file that specifies the `PIDFile` setting in the `[Service]` section. I want to clear this setting, so that a PID file is not specified for this unit.

I've created my override. Systemd sees it, so it works properly, but I'm not sure what syntax I should use to clear the setting. I've tried this in my override:

```
[Service]
PIDFile=
```

But that results in an error:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl status myservice.service
...
Jan 14 16:15:07 host systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/override.conf:1] Not an absolute path, ignoring:
```

I've also tried `PIDFile=none`, but that also results in an error. How should I clear this setting?

Comment: What version of systemd is this?

Comment: I find that clearing using `PIDFile=` _does_ work on Ubuntu `18.04` but not on `16.04`;  Did you ever find a solution that does not involve replacing the unit file as a whole?

Answer (score 18):

There's some information on the subject at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

> Various settings are allowed to be specified more than once, in which
>   case the interpretation depends on the setting. Often, multiple
>   settings form a list, and setting to an empty value "resets", which
>   means that previous assignments are ignored. When this is allowed, it
>   is mentioned in the description of the setting.

However in description of `PIDFile` directive at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html there's no information on resetting this value which according to earlier quote means it can't be reset.

Later, in section *Example 2. Overriding vendor settings*,  there's some information on removing entries from lists:

> Note that for drop-in files, if one wants to remove entries from a
>   setting that is parsed as a list (and is not a dependency), such as
>   ConditionPathExists= (or e.g. ExecStart= in service units), one needs
>   to first clear the list before re-adding all entries except the one
>   that is to be removed. See below for an example.

Cited example (edited for brevity):

Original unit:

```
[Unit]
(...)
AssertPathExists=/srv/webserver
```

Drop-in file:

```
[Unit]
(...)
AssertPathExists=
AssertPathExists=/srv/www
```

Also there's following statement:

> Note that dependencies (After=, etc.) cannot be reset to an empty
>   list, so dependencies can only be added in drop-ins. If you want to
>   remove dependencies, you have to override the entire unit.